# Fixing the appearance of the vector while keeping pas-math and mathptmx in any order?

Tags: symbols, packages, mathtools

This is MWE. It works fine if I delete `mathptmx`. But I want to use that font as well. Please let me know if you find any solution for me.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{pas-math}

\begin{document}

\Rij 


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mathptmx` lacks `\jmath`.

There are more modern packages that support Times fonts also for math.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{pas-math}

\begin{document}

\Rij

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tested with these packages and found that with *mathptmx* was very nice. Tell if you see similar packages can give a wonderful font.